# I can't sync new songs to my iPhone

Tags: iphone

Okay, so I got a new iPhone and I got some music from my Mom's iTunes library onto my iPhone with no problems, then I tried to sync some songs from my own iTunes library and I cannot. Do I need to activate homesharing or something, because I don't have this problem with my iPod. PLEASE HELP!!!

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different and congratulations on your iPhone. I believe we will need a little more information - such as - are you trying to sync music from your phone to your computer? Is it giving an error message or something? (You can edit your question.)

Answer (score 1):

From my understanding of the question, it seems to me that you are trying to sync your new iPhone with two different libraries.  This is impossible without a jailbreak (which by no means I am suggesting you do).

Since you can't sync songs from your own iTunes library, it looks like you set up your iPhone on your mom's library. I would suggest that you select 'Erase and Sync' when you try to sync your music to your own library and allow your iTunes library to manage your new iPhone. Then, I would probably import your mom's music to your iTunes library.

You can do this using Home Sharing, as you said, **but only** if both of you use the same Apple ID.  Alternatively, you could follow this [thread](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3819) and simply share the organized files and put them in your ~/Music/iTunes/iTunes Media/Music/ if you're on a Mac. Hope this helps!